# Open a specific folder by clicking menu item

Tags: java, android

I try to click on a menu item with the help of this method to open a specific folder that the app creates in internal memory when .txt file is recorded, but this is not possible even though the folder exists. Can you help me when I click the menu item to open `MyFolder`, please.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.openFolder:

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/MyFolder/");
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

            break;

}
```

Comment: Just FYI, getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated and won't be returning anything if your compile Android version is Q or higher.

Comment: I believe you are right and i have to agree with you. Is there any method you can write in the comment? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would check if there is some file explorer on the system that would handle a request of opening directories [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481929/android-how-to-check-if-file-manager-is-available) is an example.

---

Then your code should be modified to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/MyFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

---

also you may create the uri like this and I am not sure why this prefix is needed sometimes, maybe someone can explain to us:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/MyFolder/");
```